# Reduced Gröbner Basis for $u:=X^2+2XYZ$ and $v:=XY+2Y^2Z-1$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, groebner-basis

I have  $u:=X^2+2XYZ$  and $v:=XY+2Y^2Z-1$ with lex $X>Y>Z $.

I have calculated the Gröbner Basis as $G=\{ X^2+2XYZ, XY+2Y^2Z-1, X, 2Y^2Z-1 \}$.
But the question I have asks for the Reduced Gröbner Basis and I'm not really sure how I go about finding it. I think the minimal Gröbner Basis is: $\{X, 2Y^2Z-1 \}$.

Comment: Which polynomial ring is this?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y,Z]$

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia, "A Gröbner basis is termed reduced if the leading coefficient of each element of the basis is 1 and no monomial in any element of the basis is in the ideal generated by the leading terms of the other elements of the basis."

So, the first property isn't true for your last basis element. 2XYZ is generated by XY, so you couldn't have both $X^2+2XYZ$ and $XY+2Y^2Z$.

Comment: Yeah that is how I reached the minimal Grobner Basis, but im not sure what I have to do next..

Comment: Recurse until your legs give out / the process terminates. Also divide by 2.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.. i have find the minimal.. but i dont know you have to do next to ensure its a reduced Grobner Basis

Comment: Take a look at your new, smaller set of polynomials. Is it still a Groebner basis? If so, does it satisfy both properties? If so, you have a reduced Groebner basis. If not, what do you have to change about the set to make it satisfy them?

Comment: Im quite sure I have worked out the Reduced Grober Basis.. But another part to the question is ...

Describe the affine variety V(J) ... where J is the ideal generated by u and v.... What does this mean?

Comment: The leading term of your last element doesn't have coefficient 1, it has coefficient 2. So almost. For that, you should look at Wikipedia's article for an algebraic variety, but really you should pick up Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry. He and Wikipedia use Z(J) for V(J).